# Not able to close the popup on click event in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

I have used Rg.Plugins.Popup.
I have aligned close button which is aligned at top right corner 50% outside the window from right and top side as shown in below image.

[image]

Now it is showing as per expected design but issue is when I tap on it, only inward part of close button get clicked and outward part is not clickable. So not able to close popup till the time we click that inward part of Close button.

I am sharing my code for more idea.

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Padding="0,0,0,0"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Opacity="1">
        <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
               IsClippedToBounds="True"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               HasShadow="False"
               x:Name="outframe"
               Margin="0"
               CornerRadius="15"
               Padding="0"
               OutlineColor="#ffffff"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         x:Name="stkVideo"
                         Padding="0">
                <Image x:Name="ximage"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       BackgroundColor="#4A4541" />
                <video:VideoPlayer x:Name="trainingPlayer"
                                   DisplayControls="True"
                                   FillMode="ResizeAspectFill"
                                   FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                   Volume="100"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   IsVisible="false">
                </video:VideoPlayer>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.50, 0.50, -1, -1"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
            <Image Source="Play.png"
                   HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=70,Tablet=85}"
                   WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=70,Tablet=85}"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   x:Name="icnplay" />
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1" />
            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.04, -0.09, -1, -1"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" >
            <Image Source="close.png" 
                   HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=35,Tablet=45}"
                   WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=35,Tablet=45}"
                   Aspect="AspectFit">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What code changes do I need to do so that popup get close when user will click on Close button part which is outside the window as well?

Comment: Do you necessarily need the `<ContentView>` wrapping the `<Image>` tag? It's generally sufficient to add the TapGestureRecognizer on only one view if they fill the same space and invoke the same method/command.

Comment: Yes. I can add only Image tag as well but issue remains which I am facing.

Comment: It may be that the outer portion of the button is outside the AbsoluteLayout, but it's difficult to tell from your XAML snippet.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @AndrewH

Comment: If you set `ClippedToBounds="True"` on the AbsoluteLayout it should be clear whether that's true.

Comment: Yes. That the outer portion of the button is outside the AbsoluteLayout. Any hint what I can do for this?

Comment: Not a clean solution, but you could make the AbsoluteLayout larger to fit the outside portion of the button inside the AbsoluteLayout, then add a margin to your video player box to maintain its size relative to before.

Comment: Okay I will try this. Thanks @AndrewH

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrewH for your hint. It's working as expected now.

Comment: Great! I've posted the steps I suggested as an answer. Consider marking it as an answer if it's accurate to your final solution to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the close button lies outside the bounds of the `<AbsoluteLayout>`. One solution involves a few steps:

1. Make the AbsoluteLayout larger by some amount
2. Add a margin to the video player Frame equal to how much larger the AbsoluteLayout was made
3. Update the position of the close button to remain in the top right corner of the video player Frame

Now the close button is contained within the AbsoluteLayout and the entire close button area will receive and raise events for taps/clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to achieve this:

Clicking outside the yellow frame will close the everything.

The red part has a GestureRecognizer

[image]

You can achieve this by using a Grid or a Absolute layout, these views allow you to "stack" or add layers to the UI.

Code example:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
        BackgroundColor="Green"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Coso" />
            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" Text="Show popup" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Frame
            x:Name="closeFrame"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            IsVisible="false">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Grid>
        <Frame
            x:Name="popupGrid"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
            IsVisible="false">
            <Label Text="Close ouside this" TextColor="Black" />
        </Frame>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

In code behind you turn the visibile on/off of the element

Comment: Thanks for reply. If it is outside the frame then its clickable but if its some part inward and outward then outward part of close button is not clickable. That is actual problem which I am facing.

Comment: Could you edit your post and put an image of the part that you want to be clickeable but it's not?

Comment: I have updated that image. I have outlined that part with black color. 25% part of close button is inside that frame and 75% part is outside. So outside part is not clickable.

Comment: And which element handles the closing? The `xImage` ?

Comment: Image Source="close.png"  on Tapped event "TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't see that part of the code. So it looks like the part "outside" the stacklayout is not clickeable

Comment: Yes. If code wise something is wrong then let me know so that I can change accordingly